# Run a file from remote server (.exe)

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any chance to run a file from remote server (.exe) using Visual Basic for Applications in Excel?

Comment: Have you tried using a search engine ?

Comment: Of course i did. I did not find anything.

Comment: Try Shell or ShellExecute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell is a bit more straight forward.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim filename As String
    Dim retVal As Long

    filename = "c:\a.txt"
    retVal = Shell("NOTEPAD.EXE " & filename, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Or **ShellExecute** windows API

Declare this at the top of your code.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "Shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
   ByVal lpOperation As String, _
   ByVal lpFile As String, _
   ByVal lpParameters As String, _
   ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
   ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
```

Then you can call it.

```
Dim RetVal As Long
RetVal = ShellExecute(0, "open", "<full path to program>", "<arguments>", _
                    "<run in folder>", SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
```

Then evaluate the return.

The **args** are

> - hWnd The window handle of the new program's parent.
>     operation The
> - Operation to perform.
> - File The name of the file to manipulate.
> - Parameters Parameters to pass to the executable program you are about
>     to execute.
> - Directory Default directory.
> - Style The style in which

The **Operations** are

**Edit**    Launches an editor and opens the file for editing.
**Explore** Explore the folder listed in the file parameter.
**Find**    Starts the Find utility at the specified directory.
**Open**    Opens the file using the appropriate default application. For example, if the file is an HTML file, this makes the system open the file in the system's default browser.
**Print**   Prints the file.

The **Styles** are

SW_HIDE Hides the window.
SW_MAXIMIZE Maximizes the window.
SW_MINIMIZE Minimizes the window.
SW_RESTORE  Restores the window to normal (not maximized or minimized) size.
SW_SHOW Activates the window and displays it at its current size.
SW_SHOWDEFAULT  Displays the window at a default size.
SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED    Displays the window maximized.
SW_SHOWMINIMIZED    Displays the window minimized.
SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE  Displays the window minimized without giving it the focus.
SW_SHOWNA   Displays the window at its current size without giving it the focus.
SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE   Displays the window in its most recent size and position without giving it the focus.
SW_NORMAL   Displays the window at normal (not minimized or maximized) size.

Answer (score 1):

With blank Excel, no this is not possible.

Here is a suggestion, how you can achieve this:

Write a Service for the remote server, which has an operation to start the exe file. This can be done with a WCF Service for example.

If the service is running, you can call this operation from your Client(Excel).

Take a look at this [WCF beginner tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows), to start. For integration into excel, take a look [here](http://damianblog.com/2009/07/05/excel-wcf/)